# how to correct TextBox does not contain a definition for BorderRadius and no accessible extension method

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this error in 4 lines of code BorderRadius is the error

```
        DetectedLanguageText.BorderRadius = 20;
        LanguageTranslatedToText.BorderRadius = 20;
        CmbDetectedLanguage.BorderRadius = 17;
        CmbLanguageTranslateTo.BorderRadius = 17;
```

I am trying to write a translator program

I tryed retyping it with suggested lines none worked

Comment: Winforms textbox (or any other built-in Winforms control, for that matter) doesn't support rounded corners out-of-the-box - using `BorderRadius` suggest you're probably should be using something that's not built-in .net

Comment: Why (by what documentation) do you expect a BorderRadius Property to exist?

Comment: Do you use a third party UI/component library?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.